# Security Failure on django_language cookie

Tags: python, django

I ran a Pentest-Tools security audit on my website and am getting a warning that the "django_language" is missing flags "Secure, HttpOnly". I'm not really even sure what this cookie is or where it's set, but would like to clear these errors.

I set the following in the `settings.py` file, but to no affect

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Is there a way to set this in the Django project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your warning is asking not to allow javascript to have access to the CSRF cookie (client-side) Try this.

```
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

By default it is false. Checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly for more information.

Comment: But consider that this stops JS being able to access the CSRF cookie so it can't post to your server. I always accept this as a risk on PEN tests because it's better to be able to do this in modern apps that use JS.

Comment: take a look at the link I sent you. A lot of sites ignore this and I personally do as well.

Comment: Please mark this as the solution  if answered your question

Comment: But this setting only affects the csrf cookie. For me the `django_language` cookie is still "non-httponly"...